# Display all constants in 'Digest'

Tags: ruby, digest

I would like to know how to see every constant available on the `Digest` module in advance programmatically. The behaviour seen below is due to `const_missing` used [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb#L8-L25):

```
require 'digest'

Digest.constants
#=> [:Class, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance, :Base]

Digest::MD5
Digest.constants
#=> [:Class, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance, :Base, :MD5]

Digest::SHA1
Digest.constants
#=> [:Class, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance, :Base, :MD5, :SHA1]
```

Given that they are metaprogramming in possible digests, how can I know all possible available digests?

For knowledge, the ones that appear to be available in Ruby 2.4.1 should be `[:SHA256, :SHA384, :SHA512, :SHA1, :SHA2, :MD5, :RMD160]`

Comment: One way is to look in the source code: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext/digest

Comment: Except this comment seems to say otherwise:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb#L103
And you can load SHA512 that is not in the source.

Comment: Good point. Well then, since constants are lazily loaded, I don't see how you can list them without knowing them already. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "you can load sha512" - [can you, though](https://pastebin.com/UsAWkHbW)? Not in vanilla 2.4.1.

Comment: `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]`
`$ irb`
`require 'digest'`
`#=> true`
`Digest.constants`
`#=> [:Class, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance, :Base]`
`Digest::SHA512`
`#=> Digest::SHA512`
`Digest.constants`
`#=> [:Class, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :SHA256, :SHA384, :SHA512, :Instance, :Base]`

Comment: Ah, I see. It [belongs to SHA2 family](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html), which is in the source.

Comment: Oh so it is! I missed that one when scanning the files myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snipped from the current [master branch of ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e22f35ef2a671b17738929aa25372ea29d9a0a5a/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb):

```
module Digest
  def self.const_missing(name) # :nodoc:
    case name
    when :SHA256, :SHA384, :SHA512
      lib = 'digest/sha2.so'
    else
      lib = File.join('digest', name.to_s.downcase)
    end

    begin
      require lib
    rescue LoadError
      raise LoadError, "library not found for class Digest::#{name} -- #{lib}", caller(1)
    end
    unless Digest.const_defined?(name)
      raise NameError, "uninitialized constant Digest::#{name}", caller(1)
    end
    Digest.const_get(name)
  end

  # ...
end
```

...So, you can't really list all constants without knowing them already! You need to either `require` the necessary file, or reference the constant directly (which will load the file dynamically, as seen above).

Any workaround solution I could give would only be guaranteed to work for a specific version of ruby. You'd be better off to just [read the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) and load each library explicitly, unfortunately!